# How Retrieve Part Of text Using Regex Sunstring

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi All I have Query text From Query History such as "Create OR Replace Procedure PROCEDURENAME()", what i want is Procedure name such as in this string case "PROCEDURENAME" to be found using Regex Substring function. The Developer can create Procedure with this Syntax too  "CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDUREENAME()" so the reg expression should find out the name of procedure too.

Comment: in which language you want to find the regex? what language are you using here?

Comment: Anyway, Try ```/\b((?<=create (.*)procedure )\w+\(\))/gi``` for js

Comment: this is snowflake sql , thanks Ghost Ops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the procedure name and parameters, you can use the following:

```
select regexp_substr( qtext, 'CREATE.*PROCEDURE\\s+([^)]*\\))', 1, 1, 'ei', 1 ) as res from 
values('Create OR Replace Procedure PROCEDURENAME1() as xyz'),
('Create procedure PROCEDURENAME2( a varchar)'),
('Create procedure PROCEDURENAME3( a varchar, b number)')
tmp(qtext) ;

+--------------------------------------+
|                 RES                  |
+--------------------------------------+
| PROCEDURENAME1()                     |
| PROCEDURENAME2( a varchar)           |
| PROCEDURENAME3( a varchar, b number) |
+--------------------------------------+
```

If you want to parse the only procedure name, you can use this one:

```
select regexp_substr( qtext, 'CREATE.*PROCEDURE\\s+([^()]*)\(.*\)', 1, 1, 'ei', 1 ) as res from 
values('Create OR Replace Procedure PROCEDURENAME1() as xyz'),
('Create procedure PROCEDURENAME2( a varchar)'),
('Create procedure PROCEDURENAME3( a varchar, b number)')
tmp(qtext) ;

+----------------+
|      RES       |
+----------------+
| PROCEDURENAME1 |
| PROCEDURENAME2 |
| PROCEDURENAME3 |
+----------------+
```